# Where should I _append Yocto bitbake task to create work folder symlink?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Let's say I have my package at

```
host-64/tmp/work/x86_64-poky-linux/mypackage/1.2.3-r4/
```

I would like to have symlink created

```
host-64/tmp/work/x86_64-poky-linux/mypackage/latest -> 1.2.3-r4/
```

each time the new version is fetched and unpacked. 
How can I achieve that ? Which class, task should I append, extend ?

Optionally, I would like to have that for all packages or at least packages in my meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new task that comes after unpack will probably be a suitable place to add the link.

Comment: Thanks, I did it this way: do_unpack[postfuncs] += "do_latest_symlink"